# Cakephp: Remove /app/webroot on index with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp

I have a small problem of configuration with my .htaccess files:

Explanation of the problem:

- The cakephp document root is on the root where my domain points : www.example.com
- When I go to www.example.com it redirects to www.example.com/app/webroot
- Everything works fine when I browse into deeper directories eg: www.example.com/Controller/action will not have app/webroot on the url.

My .htaccess:

Root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

/app:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

/app/webroot

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference to the examples provided in the [offical docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#apache) is the position of the `RewriteBase` directive.

So, i would suggest to try the following (untested):

- `root/.htaccess`

  - remove `RewriteBase /`

    ```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/     [L]
       RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
    ```
- `app/webroot/.htaccess`

  - add the `RewriteBase` directive here and adjust to your folders

    ```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteBase /path/to/cake/app

        # exclude dirs and files
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

        # prevent invalid assets from being parsed by CakePHP
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(webroot/)?(img|css|js)/(.*)$

        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    ```

I think Cake2 used QueryStringAppend (QSA) as `RewriteRule` for index.php.
Then the last rule will be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]`, but that depends on your version of Cake.

Side-note: enable [Rewrite Logging for Apache](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteLogLevel). This helps in debugging rewrite rules. Do not forget to turn this off again.

```
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteLog "/var/apache/logs/rewrite.log
```